# Measurements and errors

Tags: electrical-resistance, measurements, error-analysis, data-analysis

I've measured several values of $V$ and $I$ in a simple circuit to determine de value of a resistance $R$:
$$R=\frac{V}{I}$$

I have a list of points $(V,I)$ with their corresponging error (from the manual of the multimeter) that I plotted and made a linear regression. The slope of the line gives me the value of $R$.

What would be the correct way to calculate the uncertanty in the value of $R$? I don't know how to calculate the instrumental errors. Each point has a $\delta V$ and a $\delta I$, but how would I combine all of them to get the instrumental error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional least-squares fitting or chi-squared minimisation route of fitting a straight line makes the implicit assumption that the errors on the x-axis quantity are negligible. If that is so, then there is no reason why you can't use the uncertainty in the gradient as the uncertainty in $R$.

I guess from your question though, that this is not the case and that $R\delta I$ is in fact comparable with $\delta V$.

One *approximate* way to proceed would be to do the fit in two steps. After the first step, increase the errors on the y-axis quantity so that they are $((\delta V)^2 + (R\delta I)^2)^{1/2}$. Re-run the fit and this gives you a new value of $R$ and its uncertainty.

[Section 15.3](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c15-3.pdf) of Numerical Recipes by Press et al. gives one perhaps less approximate route through generalisation of chi-squared fitting.

[Cameron Reed (2010)](https://www.docenti.unina.it/downloadPub.do?tipoFile=md&id=297635) describes a spreadsheet implementation of an iterative least squares method attributable to York (1966).

[Gull (1989)](http://bayes.wustl.edu/sfg/line.pdf) describes a Bayesian approach to the problem, where the output would be the posterior probability distribution for the resistance.

Finally, I offer the following: each pair of $V$ and $I$ values gives an independent estimate of $R$ with an uncertainty that could be calculated using standard error propagation formulae. You could then find the weighted mean and uncertainty in the weighted mean of these estimates. [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Resistance_measurement).